# pages.map is not a function in gatsby nodejs using axios to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I don't know what is wrong, this works perfectly as a react component using useState but I need to create dynamic pages. I created gatsby-node.js but I keep getting response such as pages.map() is not a function. I try to console log to see what is sending to **createPages** but nothing is displayed. Probably I am doing the right thing with the console.log. Nevertheless, I need help on getting the pages passed to the createPages and be able to console.log to see the data as I can see easily in a react component. [image]

```
    const path = require("path")
    const axios = require('axios')
    const url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    
        const pages  = axios.get(url).then(({data}) => {
           const pages = data["hydra:member"].map((page)=> {
               return {
                   id: page.idMgpage,
                   name:page.name,
                   city: page, 
                   parentId: page.parentId
               }
           });
           pages.map((page) => {
               page.sections =[];
               page.components =[];
               page.items = [];
                axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((section)=>{
                const sections = section.data["hydra:member"].map((section) => {
                   page.sections.push(section);
                    return {
                        content: section.content
                    }      
                });
                return sections
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((component)=> {
                const components = component.data["hydra:member"].map((component) => {
                   page.components.push(component);
                   return {
                       heading: component.heading,
                       subheading: component.subheading,
                       content: component.content
                   }
                });
                return components
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((item)=> {
                const items = item.data["hydra:member"].map((item) => {
                    page.items.push(item);
                   return {
                       itemType: item.itemType,
                       itemUrl: item.itemUrl,
                       itemContent: item.itemContent,
                       itemHeading: item.itemHeading
                   }
                });
                return items
                });
           });
           return pages
           
       });
     
     //
    
    exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
    
      const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/page.js`)
    
      pages.map(page => {
        const isHomePage = page.parentId === null
    
        const path = isHomePage
          ? `/${page.city.city}`
          : `/${page.city.city}/${page.id}`
    
        createPage({
          path: path,
          component: pageTemplate,
          context: {
            
          },
        })
      })
    }
```

From my component, I was able to use .map() on the useState and view the data. Now in the gatsby, I have Gatsby Nodejs, template component named page.js and index.js which has not code than hello.

Comment: Try to embed in createPages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need do is to use Async Await and that will be a straightforward and uncrowded approach.

```
const path = require("path")
const axios = require('axios')
exports.createPages = async ({ actions }) =>  {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/page.js`)

    const sections = [];
    const res = await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`);  
    const pages = await res.data['hydra:member'].map((result) => {
          return {
             id: result.idMgpage,
             city: result.city,
             category: result.category
            }     
    })
    pages.map( async(page) => {
          page.sections = [];
          page.components = [];
          page.items = [];
          const secData =  await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`)
          await secData.data['hydra:member'].map((result) => {
            return page.sections.push(result) 
          });
          const comData =  await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`)
          await comData.data['hydra:member'].map((result) => {
            return page.components.push(result) 
          });
          const itemsData =  await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`)
          await itemsData.data['hydra:member'].map((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            return page.items.push(result) 
          });
       sections.push( [page.id , page.category, page.city, page.sections, page.components, page.items])
      })
    
  pages.map(page => {
      console.log(page)
    const isHomePage = page.parentId === null

    const path = isHomePage
      ? `/${page.city}`
      : `/${page.city}/${page.id}`

    createPage({
      path: path,
      component: pageTemplate,
      context: {
        // meta: page.meta,
        pageId: page.id,
        category: page.category,
        sections: page.sections,
        components: page.components,
        items: page.items
      },
    })
  })
}
```

As you can see, it is easier, clean and straightforward to avoid promises.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.logs` placed in the Node files will be prompted in the terminal, not in the browser's console (it doesn't have access to the server).

In your case, `pages` is not defined in the scope of `createPages` so it becomes `undefined`, breaking your code. Try wrapping the logic inside:

```
 const path = require("path")
    const axios = require('axios')
    const url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        
    
    exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
    
        const pages  = axios.get(url).then(({data}) => {
           const pages = data["hydra:member"].map((page)=> {
               return {
                   id: page.idMgpage,
                   name:page.name,
                   city: page, 
                   parentId: page.parentId
               }
           });
           pages.map((page) => {
               page.sections =[];
               page.components =[];
               page.items = [];
                axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((section)=>{
                const sections = section.data["hydra:member"].map((section) => {
                   page.sections.push(section);
                    return {
                        content: section.content
                    }      
                });
                return sections
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((component)=> {
                const components = component.data["hydra:member"].map((component) => {
                   page.components.push(component);
                   return {
                       heading: component.heading,
                       subheading: component.subheading,
                       content: component.content
                   }
                });
                return components
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((item)=> {
                const items = item.data["hydra:member"].map((item) => {
                    page.items.push(item);
                   return {
                       itemType: item.itemType,
                       itemUrl: item.itemUrl,
                       itemContent: item.itemContent,
                       itemHeading: item.itemHeading
                   }
                });
                return items
                });
           });
           return pages
           
       });


      const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/page.js`)
    
      pages.map(page => {
        const isHomePage = page.parentId === null
    
        const path = isHomePage
          ? `/${page.city.city}`
          : `/${page.city.city}/${page.id}`
    
        createPage({
          path: path,
          component: pageTemplate,
          context: {
            
          },
        })
      })
    }
```

---

`pages` it seems to be an object (because you are returning it) and you can loop through an object using a `map` loop.

Create an empty array and push each page before looping it.

Another trial would be using an `async`/`await` approach:

```
 const path = require("path")

    const axios = require('axios')
    const url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        
    
    exports.createPages = async ({ actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
    
        const pages  = await axios.get(url).then(({data}) => {
           const pages = data["hydra:member"].map((page)=> {
               return {
                   id: page.idMgpage,
                   name:page.name,
                   city: page, 
                   parentId: page.parentId
               }
           });
           pages.map((page) => {
               page.sections =[];
               page.components =[];
               page.items = [];
                axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((section)=>{
                const sections = section.data["hydra:member"].map((section) => {
                   page.sections.push(section);
                    return {
                        content: section.content
                    }      
                });
                return sections
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((component)=> {
                const components = component.data["hydra:member"].map((component) => {
                   page.components.push(component);
                   return {
                       heading: component.heading,
                       subheading: component.subheading,
                       content: component.content
                   }
                });
                return components
                });
                axios.get(`http://xxxxxxxxxx?page=${page.id}`).then((item)=> {
                const items = item.data["hydra:member"].map((item) => {
                    page.items.push(item);
                   return {
                       itemType: item.itemType,
                       itemUrl: item.itemUrl,
                       itemContent: item.itemContent,
                       itemHeading: item.itemHeading
                   }
                });
                return items
                });
           });
           return pages
           
       });


      const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/page.js`)
    
      pages.map(page => {
        const isHomePage = page.parentId === null
    
        const path = isHomePage
          ? `/${page.city.city}`
          : `/${page.city.city}/${page.id}`
    
        createPage({
          path: path,
          component: pageTemplate,
          context: {
            
          },
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: The same error, pages.map() is not a function

Comment: Well, in that case, you are not fetching the data properly. Try to debug if your axios request is gathering all the data properly and the promise is working as expected

Comment: Can I send you the endpoints to try it? I am doing result in react component with useState which I can share with you. This is my email kiddiestvshow@gmail.com

Comment: Place a console.log in the resolved promise to check if it fetches the value

Comment: Please check the code update... I tried to add the react component, which you can run and see the output.

Comment: It behaves different on the server and in the browser. Place  a console.log after: `const pages = data["hydra:member"].map((page)=> {` and before the return

Comment: Yes it returns values for every step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228213/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-game-zone).